# How to change default CollectionEditor for PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms

I use `PropertyGrid` in WinForms. Can I change the default `CollectionEditor`? I can show custom `CollectionEditor` by `Editor` attribute like this:

```
[Editor("MyProgram.CustomCollectionEditor , MyProgram, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=neutral", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```

But I don't want to use it for all properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EditorAttribute` on a property so only properties with the attribute applied to has a custom editor.

I think [How to: Take control over the Collection Editor's PropertyGrid](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-take-control-over-collection.html) may be helpful in what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i know. I can use `EditorAttrube` for only properties. but i wonder about can i change `PropertyGrid`'s default `CollectionEditor`? so, maybe I change the config or change `PropertyGrid`'s property and so on

Comment: Updated answer, hopefully that link can give you some guidance on how to get into the internals of PropertyGrid. It may not be a solution to your problem, but its a place to start digging.